# Can't use Control key while setting shortcut keys for compiz

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, compiz

I might got a problem along with my Xorg config, all control keys are now shown as `<Primary>`, what is that?

I just mapped <kbd>Capslock</kbd> to <kbd>Left Control</kbd>, and I can't set the shortcut key to <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> now

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the 'Utility:Inotify' Plugin and edit ~/.config/compiz/Default.ini

As you can see, the `<Primary>` is not written to the ini-file. You can now write `<Control>`. The shortcut is active when the file is saved.

example:

```
[core]
as_toggle_window_maximized_key = <Alt><Super>m
as_toggle_window_maximized_horizontally_key = <Control><Alt>m
as_toggle_window_maximized_vertically_key = <Control><Shift>m
```